# Resize a control inside a Ribbon Panel

Tags: ribbon, dotnetbar

I have a form with a ribbon bar and I want the controls that are on the `RibbonPanel` to resize with the rest of the form.  The docked `RibbonControl` resizes fine and the RibbonPanel resizes with it but the controls that `Docked`/`Anchored`  on the RibbonPanel do not resize.

How do you get controls on a ribbon panel to Dock or Anchor correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a work around I placed a normal `Panel` control inside of the `RibbonPanel` control, and docked all the controls I want to resize in that panel.  Using a simple resize method and a couple event handlers to dynamically resize that panel, the controls now `Anchor` and `Dock` normally while on a RibbonPanel.

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    Resize()
End Sub

Private Sub RibbonControl1_SelectedRibbonTabChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RibbonControl1.SelectedRibbonTabChanged
    Resize()
End Sub

Private Sub Resize()
    Select Case RibbonControl1.SelectedRibbonTabItem.Name
        Case "RibbonTabItem1"
            Panel1.Size = RibbonPanel1.Size
        Case "RibbonTabItem2"
            Panel2.Size = RibbonPanel2.Size
        Case ...
    End Select
End Sub
```